# Conditional fusion of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$array2 = ['d', 'e', 'f'];
```

Please tell me how to get to the output I received:

```
$array3 = [
    'a-d',
    'a-e',
    'a-f',
    'b-d',
    'b-e',
    'b-f',
    'c-d',
    'c-e',
    'c-f',
];
```

Comment: your index/keys are duplicates, and that will never work

Comment: Sorry, I edit task...

Comment: What's "conditional" about this?

Comment: I'm out of flags for the day :(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no evidence of any attempt to solve the problem by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like homework but you could do the following

```
$array3 = [];
foreach($array2 as $value) {
    foreach($array1 as $index) {
       $array3[] = $index . '-' . $value;
    }
}
```

But this is pretty simple PHP, you should really take a course or read a book/tutorial.